# How to restore a floated window when opening Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

With Visual Studio open I like to float a separate window.  For example: open a TFS query, right click the tab and select Float. After floating it and closing/reopening Visual Studio the floated window is no longer open. Further, when I go to reopen Visual Studio that particular window it is not floating anymore but opens where it did before I floated it (in the 'Main Document Group').

**Addition:** There are two kinds of floating. The floated window that DOESN'T result in another program icon in the task bar works (for instance, floating solution explorer as Igor suggests). But any floated window that gives a second task bar program icon (in your taskbar you have the main visual studio and then you have a second window) will not stay.

Does anyone know how to force VS to either:

1. remember if the window was floated when reopening it after a VS close/reopen
2. automatically reopen the floated window(s) that were open when I last closed VS

I obviously would prefer #2.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know layout settings are stored under `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings`. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbhkx167.aspx)

The settings file can be set via `|Tools|Options|Environment|Import and Export Settings|`. Check whether you have access to the file that is set there or/and try changing it.

Visual Studio also might store window positions in the Registry as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb165452%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have my settings file saved.  Even if I export my settings file with a window floated, close, reopen and import the saved settings the window doesn't reopen floated and if I manually open the window it doesn't restore floated. I may try editing the registry

Comment: Is it just the TFS window? Does positioning of say the solution explorer work? It definitely does here. And the changes are persisted in the vssettings file. I checked the diff, the tag `<wm:ToolWindowView Name="ST:0:0:{3ae79031-e1bc-11d0-8f78-00a0c9110057}"` defines the position of the solution explorer...

Comment: That is weird - there are two types of floating. I have updated my question to be more clear